# How to Connect Python Script to CLR winform C++ in Visual Studio

Tags: python, c++, winforms, clr

I'm planning to add simple python script to my clr winform.

*This is what i' m planning to do*

1. Get the value from text box.
2. Click the Solve button.
3. Add 10 to the value that get from text box (This should be done by the python script)
4. Display the answer.

**This is the form**
[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USetg.png)

**This is the C++ code**
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9TDL.png)

**This is the Python Code**
def add10(num):
return num + 10

** I have saved the python file in my desktop named as "add10.py"

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKkXV.png)

but this doesn't work.
I have changed the python file location. But it still doesn't work. anyone have any idea about that? Thank you.! Hope you understand what i want to do.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.